# asp net mvc - have a model attribute reference another model attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to add 'Price' on class B as reference to 'Price' on class A.
I want to avoid the repetition of the declaration of a property:

```
public class A{

    // ... stuff 

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price (Euros)")]
    [Range(1, 1000)]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    // ... more stuff 
}

public class B{

    // ... stuff 

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price (Euros)")]
    [Range(1, 1000)]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    // ... more stuff 
}
```

So, for example, if in class A i want to change the range i don't want to 
have to remember which other classes have the same property.

Answer (score 1):

What about inheritance?

```
public class A{

    // ... stuff 
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price (Euros)")]
    [Range(1, 1000)]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    // ... more stuff 
}

public class B : A{

    // ... stuff 

    // ... more stuff 
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention interface in your answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a constant for this

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const int PriceMin = 1;
    public const int PriceMax = 1000;
}

....


[Range(Constants.PriceMin, Constants.PriceMax)]
```

Or you can inherit the Range attribute like

```
public class MyRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public MyRangeAttribute()
       :base(1, 1000)
    {
    }
}
```

then you can just do

```
[MyRange]
```

and when you want to change the value just change it inside MyRangeAttribute.cs